# Autorefresh git log after commit when running in the Terminal

Tags: git, git-log

Is it possible git log to be auto refreshed after commit or can I use another utillity in the Terminal to see list of all previous commits which auto refreshes itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
 while true; do clear; git log -2 | cat; sleep 5; done
```

This shows the top two git log entries, refreshing every 5 seconds.
The "| cat" is there to avoid git opening a pager.

This does not get new remote changes, though.

Comment: useless use of cat, and most systems have a `watch` command to replace the while, true, clear and sleep. IMHO that's a useless 11-4 = 7 "words"; oh and all the interpunction. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157312/auorefresh-git-log-after-commit-when-running-in-the-terminal/7157609#7157609)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know `watch`. A new tool for the box! And the usage of cat is not useless, even though it can be replaced by `--no-pager`.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer the following, because it's cleaner than the other solution:

```
watch git log -2
```

Much easier to type

If you want to refresh each 5 seconds, instead of 2 seconds, use

```
watch -n 5 git log -2
```

---

For those without `watch` function/binary:

```
function watch()
{
    local delay=2
    local lines=$(tput lines)
    lines=$((${lines:-25} - 1))

    if [[ "$1" -eq "-n" ]]; then
        shift 
        delay=$((${1:-2}))
        shift 
    fi

    while true
    do
            clear
        "$@" | head -n $lines
        sleep $delay
    done
}
```

Comment: Is 'watch' available on Mac, cause in the Terminal the command couldn't be found?

Comment: @cerruti: perhaps not then. That's a shame. I'll add a bash function definition to do the same

Comment: added a bash sample function `watch`; it tries to determine the number of lines in the terminal (or default to 25)

Comment: For those with `watch` binary: use `watch -c` to preserve colour formatting.

Comment: watch -c didn't work for me.. is there an alternative?

Comment: `watch --color git -c color.ui=always log` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Of course, we could use `sleep` solutions described in the other answers, but they rely on timely updates, which is not beautiful, and will cause delays between commits and updates of the log.

Instead, what we would like to see are asynchronous updates that happen precisely when the logs are updated.  In Linux we have `inotify-tools` ([download here](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#wiki-getting), they're really small to install and do not have prerequisites) to watch for filesystem events, such as creation and modification of files.

```
inotifywait -m -r -e modify -e create -e close_write -e attrib .git/ | while read ; do
  clear
  git --no-pager log -2
done
```

We recursively watch for events that happen in `.git` folder of your repository (where Git modifies files on commits).  I've just tested the set of watched events, and it seems enough to update the log on commits and branch switches only.

Comment: Of note, you only really need to watch `.git/HEAD` when passing no arguments to `git log`; and only need to watch `.git/HEAD` and `.git/refs` if only passing branches or tags to `git log`. (The only time you need to watch the entire `.git` dir is if you expect to be passing specific *object names* to `git log`.)

Comment: (Also of note, if you're working in a JavaScript environment, check out `npm install chokidar-cli` for filesystem-watching, which is the idiomatic tool used by Gulp, Karma, Browserify, webpack, etcetcetc.)

Comment: how would you do this for entire git history with pagination? it only works for me by pressing q